# the date of signature and rsa key id aren't match

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, help

When I had finish the verifying step, I saw that line on the site "gpg: Signature made Tue 24 Jan 2015 09:29:09 AM CET using RSA key ID D40814E0" does not match with my line.

my line has wrong date and rsa key id. it's strange that id is match with the last 8 numbers of the last subkey fingerprints that on the site. it is "c3c07136"

does something wrong with signature or i can use this package?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tor Browser developers use the key [`0x4E2C6E8793298290`](http://pool.sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?search=0x4E2C6E8793298290&op=vindex) for signing the releases:

```
pub   rsa4096/0x4E2C6E8793298290 2014-12-15 [C] [expires: 2020-08-24]
      Key fingerprint = EF6E 286D DA85 EA2A 4BA7  DE68 4E2C 6E87 9329 8290
uid                   Tor Browser Developers (signing key) <torbrowser@torproject.org>
sub   rsa4096/0x7017ADCEF65C2036 2014-12-15 [S] [expires: 2017-08-25]
      Key fingerprint = 5242 013F 02AF C851 B1C7  36B8 7017 ADCE F65C 2036
sub   rsa4096/0x2E1AC68ED40814E0 2014-12-15 [S] [expires: 2017-08-25]
      Key fingerprint = BA1E E421 BBB4 5263 180E  1FC7 2E1A C68E D408 14E0
sub   rsa4096/0xD1483FA6C3C07136 2016-08-24 [S] [expires: 2018-08-24]
      Key fingerprint = A430 0A6B C93C 0877 A445  1486 D148 3FA6 C3C0 7136
```

This key has lots of subkeys and several are near the expiry date (`expires:`). So the devs have chosen to create a new subkey with the id `0xD1483FA6C3C07136` or short `0xC3C07136`. So the website lists the main key and you saw the subkey. So everything looks fine from this site.